# Copy large file from sftp

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, sftp, spring-camel, camel-file

I am copying file from ftp to local system and file is in gigs. I notice that each time when I tried to copy file in iteration it overrides the content.

`<route id="ftp" > <"ftp://xxx@myftp.com/ftp-test/?password=mypassword"/> <to uri="file://filepath/temp"/> </route>`

Tried using .done extension but didn't worked also tried to copy file to another folder but that's also overlapping.

Comment: So if you wanted to append the new contents (what you didn't tell us), what does the problem have to do with file being "large"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this.

```
<route id="incoming" >
    <from uri="file://my/path/incoming"/>
    <to uri="file://my/path/incoming/temp?fileExist=Append"/>
</route>
```